# lodash remove array item from nested object

Tags: typescript, lodash

Given a JSON object and a path, how can I remove a specific element?

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'
path = ["roles", 0]
devs = {
  category: '',
  roles: [{role:"a role"}, {role:"another role"}]
}
```

I need to remove first element of roles array. path and devs are dynamically set so I cannot be specific like

```
_.remove(devs.roles, function(v,i,a){return i === _.last(path) ;})
```

Tried to use unset but it gives still an array with 2 elements

```
_.unset(devs, path)
```

My desired output is the following:

```
devs = {
      category: '',
      roles: [{role:"another role"}]
    }
```

Any clues? Thanks

Comment: This cannot be done in a type-safe way using Lodash. Are you interested in other approaches? (i.e lenses)

Comment: for this part I am unable to be type-safe

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
_.unset(devs, "roles[0]");
```

Note this might bomb if the array is empty so I would put some safe guards around this.

Comment: Hi @beautifulcoder, thanks for the answer. Anyway path is dynamic so I cannot hardcode the unset path